# Twitter API Rate limit exceeded explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter

I know that [Twitter limits the number of request](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting) you can made by user for an application but I did not understand it well.

I'm using mainly Twitter API to Oauth then retrieve User's lists. So I can only call 15 GET within 15 minutes window per User ? This is incredibly low or I'm not doing things right ? I always get Rate limit exceeded, mostly when I'm doing some dev...

When the user is authenticated and load a page I'm doing this to connect the user :

```
@twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key    = xx
  config.consumer_secret = xx
  config.access_token        = xx
  config.access_token_secret = xx
end
```

Then to retrieve his lists something like :

```
@twitter_client.list_timeline(list_id).each do |tweet|
  tweet.text
end
```

I've done some test and the result annoy me a little. A User cannot (for example) reload the page more than 15 times before getting rate limited. Unfortunately, I cannot prevent Users from navigate into the website...

The solution to bypass the rate limit error would be to [use the Rate Limit feature](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/RateLimiting.md) from [the gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) but in this case, the User has no reason to stay on the website if it does not display anything.

Thank you for letting me know if my interpretation / implementation of the Twitter API is good. Feel free to give me some tricks about it.